# Multiple ExecStartPre in systemd unit override files. Does systemd guarantee execution order?

Tags: linux, systemd

From various sources, it seems like having ExecStartPre in an override conf file is executed in order and after the main service file.

But is this guaranteed by systemd itself? Also what happens if the ExecStartPre is a nohup of some sort? Or a long running process?

Answer (score 3):

See `man systemd.unit`:

> Along with a unit file `foo.service`, a "drop-in" directory
> `foo.service.d/` may exist. All files with the suffix "`.conf`" from
> this directory will be merged in the alphanumeric order and parsed after
> the main unit file itself has been parsed.

And [`man systemd.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html):

> ##### `ExecStartPre=`,`ExecStartPost=`
>
> Additional commands that are executed before or after the command
> in `ExecStart=`, respectively. Syntax is the same as for `ExecStart=`,
> except that multiple command lines are allowed and **the commands are
> executed one after the other, serially**.
>
> [...]
>
> **Note that `ExecStartPre=` may not be used to start long-running processes.** All processes forked off by processes invoked via
> `ExecStartPre=` will be killed before the next service process is
> run.
>
> **Note that if any of the commands specified in `ExecStartPre=`**, `ExecStart=`, or `ExecStartPost=` fail (and are not prefixed with
> "`-`", see above) or **time out before the service is fully up**,
> execution continues with commands specified in `ExecStopPost=`, the
> commands in `ExecStop=` are skipped. [...]

So:

> But is this guaranteed by systemd itself?

Yes.

> Also what happens if the ExecStartPre is a nohup of some sort? Or a
> long running process?

If it times out, it gets killed and the service proceeds to `ExecStopPost`.

Comment: What is the time out for an ExecStartPre? Is it configurable? It doesn't mention how long each ExecStart{Pre|Post} blocks till it's killed.

Comment: [90s by default](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html#DefaultTimeoutStartSec=) (but it's not for an individual `ExecStartPre` command - it's for startup in total). You can use [`TimeoutStartSec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#TimeoutStartSec=) to configure it.